# How to update firefox while keep all my current stuff?

Tags: updates, firefox

I'm using the firefox which is not the Ubuntu's version. Downloading from [Mozilla's website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/).

The way I do this is to unpack the package and put it in the folder /opt/firefox/. Now my version is 38.01 and I want to update to 38.05. Firefox won't update automatically, so I need to download the newest package from the website. I think I still need to copy it to the folder /opt/firefox/.

However, when doing that I think all my extension's settings will be lost. Also the bookmarks and the history etc. will need to be sync again.

So the question is: **How to update using the downloaded package *as if I update automatically* and affect nothing with my current settings**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bookmarks and extensions will not be lost.

All bookmarks and extensions and preferences are stored in `/home/user/.mozilla` so replacing `/opt/firefox` should be absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes, you are abosolutely right!

Comment: I know, I can't accept too soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your profile location: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile
2. Back it up just in case
3. Download new firefox version
4. Start firefox with `firefox --ProfileManager` and make sure that your profile location is selected or create a new profile that points to your profile data.